# HTML code that generate custom url with user given value

Tags: url

Hi i am want an html code that replace **XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX** value from my url with my user given value and generate a new url

Below is My URL 
https://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?method=stream.publish&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com&api_key=192236710846214 &picture= **XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX**%3Flvh%3D1& source=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61636013/achille.swf&set=a.106020872877897.12204.100004099541771&type=1&theater &name=Posted by Karthik%C2%AD&caption=Kaur & comment%C2%AD&description=%C2%  For Fun

Comment: I think you just revealed your secret API key.  You probably should change that now.

Answer (score 0):

Best is that you use php:

```
<?php 
$x="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$location= "https://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?
           method=stream.publish&redirect_uri=https://www.
           facebook.com&api_key=192236710846214 &picture=".
           $x.
           "%3Flvh%3D1& source=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com
           /u/61636013/achille.swf&set=a.106020872877897.12204.
           100004099541771&type=1&theater &name=Posted by 
           Karthik%C2%AD&caption=Kaur & comment%C2%AD&description=%C2%";
header("Lcation:".$location);
?>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, i am very new for this coding, please help i this. i want to keep this code you given in my blogger. that includes a input area for XXXXXXXXX value and having a generate button that opens in new tab after clicking along with new url that is generated